# Paint the contents of an OpenGL front buffer into a custom destination

Tags: opengl

I am using OpenGL 4.0 (although I am also interested in a solution for previous versions). I basically want to access the front buffer, or the back buffer before the swap, an copy/paint it into my own buffer, so I can either save it in a file, or stream it, etc. Extra points if I can access directly as a YUV 420 file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`glReadPixels`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glReadPixels). Preferably into a [pixel buffer](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object), if you like performance.

> Extra points if I can access directly as a YUV 420 file.

It's not stored as YUV 420.